# Rescan for matching kernel modules

Tags: kernel-modules, modprobe

So normaly during boot or when a device is hotplugged Linux loads kernel modules for hardware based on modaliases.

Is there a way to manually trigger this for a specific device or a general "rescan" for the whole system?

e.g. I have a pci device which had no matching driver during boot. Then I install a driver package with several modules. Now I want the system the automatically pick the right one based on modaliases and load it like it would on a reboot, without actually rebooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`udevadm trigger`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/udevadm.8.html) for this, on a specific device or the whole system.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.

But it somehow doesn't work for acpi devices:
I tried `sudo udevadm trigger /sys/bus/acpi/devices/CLV0001:00`, `sudo udevadm trigger /sys/bus/acpi/devices/CLV0001:00 -c add`, and `sudo udevadm trigger /sys/bus/acpi/devices/CLV0001:00 -c change` but the previously unloaded module with `alias: acpi*:CLV0001:*` didn't get load in again.

Comment: Never mind: `-c add` did work, I just botched up my `lsmod | grep` command xD